# What data type should I use for my Date column in a new SQL table?

Tags: sql-server, date, types, sqldatatypes

I am creating a new SQL table which will have a date column, which will contain only Month and Year (eg: November 2014). My concern is that I will need to match this column in a query to do a JOIN. A relevant extract of that query is shown below:

```
    (
   SELECT 
     ReservationStayID,
     datename(m,StayDate) + ' ' + cast(datepart(yyyy,StayDate) as varchar) as [MTH],
     count(*) AS [Nights Spent],
     avg(RateAmount) as [Rate],
     min(CreatedOn) as CreatedOn,
     min(StayDate) as [DateOfArrival],
     max(StayDate) as [DateOfDeparture]
   FROM ReservationStayDate
   GROUP BY ReservationStayID, datename(m,StayDate) + ' ' + cast(datepart(yyyy,StayDate) as varchar)
 ) x ON x.ReservationStayID = b.ReservationStayID
```

The date column of my new table will be matched with the output from line 3 of the query above (that is, datename(m,StayDate.....as [MTH])

I just want to get it right in my new table so that I don't mess up things later when doing JOINS,etc.

I've read that I can use smalldate, or split the Month and Year as Varchar in 2 columns. So, what would you recommend?

Comment: Dear admin, 

Please delete question if you believe it is opinion based. Since I gave an example of my SQL query based on an actual situation, I thought the question is related to facts and hence, answers provided would be relevant to this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are sure that you will never ever use the whole date you should go with two separate fields for month and year but you do must have those values split both sides of the join otherwise there will be no advantage going this path: `month name` will be a varchar/nvarchar column but `year` should be an integer as it will always be a number.

one of the advantages of two separate columns is that you don't have to make the math at every join so you must have these values separate both sides of the join.

what i mean is that you have to modify the structure of table `ReservationStayDate` also, adding month and year as sparate values; the easiest solution is to create two [calculated columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

if you can use persisted calculated columns you could also have indexes on these columns and that will likely improve performances when joining & searching.

THE advantage i  see: if you need (and use only) the information 'month' and 'year' it is cumbersome and costly to translate a 'date' information wherever you need 'month' and 'year' in the whole application. you can make classes, helper methods and so on but if you store the 'clean' information in the database it is easier to use and maintain it at all levels.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use one datetime column

Comment: why? is there any reason to prefer that datatype?